# Changing tyre size on a Specialized Vado 3

Tags: tire

Hi I have Vado 3 Specialized ebike with 700x47c tyres fitted. Need to change soon. What are your thoughts on downsizing to a 700x38c tyre to reduce road friction and improve rolling on tarmac?

Comment: Absolutely no problem there. Just get e-bike tyres, they have a tougher compound and are less prone to excessive wear. They should be available at a well stocked bikestore.

Comment: One of the real world fallacies is smaller tires have less resistance. https://www.cyclingweekly.com/news/product-news/are-wider-tyres-really-faster-160403 (and many others) expose the virtues of fat feet.